# Creating a pcap file

Tags: c, linux, udp, pcap, libpcap

I need to save UDP packets to a file and would like to use the pcap format to reuse the various tools available (wireshark, tcpdump, ...).
There are some information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309773/c-writing-structs-to-a-file-pcap) but I can't find how to write the global file header 'struct pcap_file_header'.

```
pcap_t* pd = pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW, 65535);
pcap_dumper_t* pdumper = pcap_dump_open(pd, filename);

struct pcap_file_header file_hdr;
file_hdr.magic_number = 0xa1b2c3d4;
file_hdr.version_major = 2;
file_hdr.version_minor = 4;
file_hdr.thiszone = 0;
file_hdr.sigfigs = 0;
file_hdr.snaplen = 65535;
file_hdr.linktype = 1;

// How do I write file_hdr to m_pdumper?

while( (len = recvmsg(sd, &msg_hdr, 0)) > 0 )
  pcap_dump((u_char*)m_pdumper, &m_pcap_pkthdr, (const u_char*)&data);
```

How should I write the global file header? 
If there is no specific pcap function available, how can I retrieve the file descriptor to insert the header using write()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to write that header, `pcap_open_dead` should do it for you. You only need to fill out and write that header yourself if you want to write the file directly instead of using `pcap_dump` and friends. There's an example [here](http://seclists.org/tcpdump/2010/q2/22) of a trivial program write out a pcap file with those functions.

---

**original answer**, concerning writing the file directly:

I can't remember exactly how this works, but I wrote a patch to `redir` a while ago that would write out pcap files, you may be able to use it as an example.

You can find it attached to [this debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526401). (bug link fixed.)

Some of it is for faking the ethernet and IP headers, and may not be applicable as you're using `pcap_dump_open` and `pcap_dump` where as the patch linked above writes out the `pcap` file without using any libraries, but I'll leave this here anyway in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you have done everything using regular file write() calls. I am using pcap_dump() and can't figure where to get the file descriptor.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Updated above. I've left the original answer since even with `pcap_dump` you'll still need to fake an IP header, and the patch linked above may help with that.

Comment: True, no need to write the global file header, I just verified.

Comment: use pcap_fileno() to get a file descriptor from a pcap_t*. You can however call pcap_dump() directly to write packets to a pcap_t

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in UDP and TCP only, you should use `DLT_EN10MB` instead of `DLT_RAW` ( cf [pcap_open_dead to simulate full UDP packets capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114739/pcap-open-dead-to-simulate-full-udp-packets-capture) ).

It is much better when editing in WireShak.