# pcap_open_dead to simulate full UDP packets capture

Tags: c, linux, udp, pcap, libpcap

Following up on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113653/creating-a-pcap-file) about pcap file creation, I now would like to simulate the saving of a full UDP packet, including the Ethernet, IP and UDP headers.

Which DLT_XXX type should I use? I believe pcap_dump() [skips](http://seclists.org/tcpdump/2010/q2/22) the Ethernet header when using pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW, 65535).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simulate a full UDP-over-IP-over-Ethernet packet, you want `DLT_EN10MB` (the "10MB" in the name is historical; `DLT_EN10MB` really means "all types of Ethernet").

(`DLT_RAW` is for packets where the lowest-level headers are for IP; it doesn't skip the Ethernet header, it means that you don't have to provide an Ethernet header and, in fact, it requires that you *don't* provide one - if you *do* provide one, it'll be written to the file, which will confuse programs reading the file, as they'll expect the packets to begin with an IPv4 or IPv6 header, not an Ethernet header.)